# Vue: uncaught reference: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that contains a form. On submit button click an alert method should appear. However when the button is clicked I only get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: greet is not defined` in console which disappears very quickly.

```
<template>
    <div class="text-breakdown">
        <h3 class = "title">Text Breakdown</h3>

        <form onsubmit="greet()">
            <textarea type="text" id = "breakdown-text"
                  placeholder="Enter your text here">
            </textarea>

            <button class = "custom-button dark-button"
                    type="submit">Breakdown</button>
        </form>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default  {
        methods:  {
            greet()  {
                alert("Hello!");
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the browser is trying to find the `greet` method in global scope as you are calling a native `onsubmit` submit method. You just need to bind the `submit` event to vue instance using [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) directive like:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="greet">
```

Or use the `v-on` shorthand like:

```
<form @submit.prevent="greet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Review the event bindings:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

You will probably want to bind your `greet` function to the form using Vue syntax and not just generic `onsubmit`.

At a minimum it could be:

```
<form :submit="greet"> .... </form>
```

Comment: probably want `:submit.prevent="greet"` or the page will reload

Comment: Thank you. The code in the answer does work - but the page does reload. `:submit.prevent` however results in: `error  'v-bind' directives don't support the modifier 'prevent'  vue/valid-v-bind`

Comment: @submit.prevent="greet"